# Insert data from forms into datasets

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, dataset

I have a dataset set up with 3 fields, ID username and password. I want the user to type in a new username and passoword and this then gets saved back to the dataset. How do I take what has been typed in and save it into the data set?

So far this is the code I have

```
usersTableAdapters.UsersTableAdapter user = new usersTableAdapters.UsersTableAdapter();
user.usersDataTable usertable = user.GetData();
```

This allows me to connect to the data set although I am not sure how to take the values the user will enter in the input boxes and save them back to the dataset?

Comment: If I get it right then refer this [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms233812%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) link.

Comment: Have you databound the dataset to the textboxes?  I am guessing no.

Comment: I am unsure what this means so you are correct the answer is no.

Comment: This is a great write-up about [databinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

A quick and dirty implementation of this would look like this:

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds.Tables.Add(textBox1.Text);  //I did this in Winforms so, your result may vary.
ds.Tables.Add(textBox2.Text);  //Same here.

if (ds.HasChanges())  //Check if the DataSet has changes.
   ds.AcceptChanges(); //If it does, commit them.
```