# TableAdapter error - namespace not found

Tags: c#, asp.net, dataset

I am trying to insert data back into my database through a dataset. My database table is called Users and the dataset is called userDataSet. I am getting an error which says

```
The type or namespace name 'UserDataSet' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Also am I connecting to the datasets in the correct way, I am not sure how I check if the connection is correct.

I am using [this MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms233812(v=vs.80).aspx) for reference.

```
userTableAdapters.UsersTableAdapter us = new userTableAdapters.UsersTableAdapter();
    user.UsersDataTable usertable = us.GetData();

    UserDataSet.UsersRow newUsersRow;
    newUsersRow = userDataSet.Users.NewUsersRow();
   newUsersRow.Username = TextBox1.Text;
    newUsersRow.Password = TextBox2.Text;

    this.userDataSet.Users.Rows.Add(newUsersRow);

    this.usersTableAdapter.Update(this.userDataSet.Users);
```

Comment: Is UserDataSet defined in an assembly that is not referenced?

Comment: I have no idea what this means, I am very new to windows programming and c#

Comment: What is the exact exception here?  In the title you mention a TableAdapter and in the body of your post, you reference a DataSet.  They are two different things.

Comment: I think I am confusing my self, my real question I am trying to solve is this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16471253/insert-data-from-forms-into-datasets this question has come to light through trying to solve that

Comment: I answered that original question, hehe.  Can you please edit your post to include ALL of your code?

Comment: This is all my code, I didn't notice you answered sorry late night!!I am trying to connect to my dataset which is called userDataSet and then insert back into the db.